# How to properly handle http errors in episerver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I want to handle 404 and 500 errors on my site that using episerver cms. It have to support custom pages created by site editors but also have fallback to static page and preserve url. I read many topics about this, for [example](http://codeworx-blog.azurewebsites.net/2016/12/12/how-to-add-custom-error-pages-in-episerver-cms/), but i can't fully understand what's going on. On the bases of this article, how exactly it works and what i have to change to accomplish my goal? As far as i know, "httperrors" module comes first and redirect to specified page (like 404). It removes statusCode and proceed to controller of 404 page. But when "customErrors" module, "errorpage" controller and "errorhandler" class is using?

Comment: Hi Shumek,
What version of EPi are you using?

Comment: according to license information it's Episerver CMS 7.5

Comment: What do you mean by "fallback to static page"? You may find it easier to use `<httpErrors>` to preserve the URL while displaying an Episerver page as the 404 page.